# Select 2 onChange() trigger selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using [select2](https://select2.github.io/) for select box which gets populated on API call. I want to call another API when I select an item from the dropdown list which now works like this:

```
<select id="person-select" onchange="callAnotherApi()" style="width: 100%">
</select>
```

API gets called whenever I pick some other value, but not when I pick the first one (which is already selected by default, so no `onChange()` is triggered). `onClick()` doesn't function here. I am wondering if I can disable having the first record selected or something to make this work?

Comment: show me full code

Comment: which part? `select2` is loaded, function triggers another API, it is just a question for the first default selected value

Comment: This is what I found: "This behaviour exists not because Select2 is forcing it, but because the browser is auto-selecting the first option for you. We can't control that, we can only work around it. Your best option is to use the placeholder support in Select2 and include a blank option tag as your default selection."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable first option and put placeholder text:

```
 <select>
    <option val="null" disabled selected> select an answer</option>
    <option val="one">one</option>
</select>
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sL4fLnhn/

```
   $('select').on('change', function(){
      $('select option:disabled').remove();
  });
   $('select').select2();
```

Comment: Slick and simple. Thanks